# Need Help on Red5 in Oflademo - NetConnection.Connect.Closed

Tags: streaming, ubuntu-12.04, red5, rtmp

I'm trying to use some features in video streaming like adaptive bitrate streaming (automatic bandwith check that adjusts video quality based on customer bandwith). From sources that I got, I am told that I can use Red5 to achieve it. I have tested Red5 and it's almost successful but it's not working in the end.

Red5 is successfully activated in terminal, and from what I can see in localhost:5080 it seems to be working, but when I go to localhost:5080/demos/ofla_demo.html, I got `NetConnection.Connect.Closed when I connect.`

Is there code that I need to modify to enable run oflademo or is there anything else ?

Here is the Red5 log in terminal and in the web browser:

```
Red5 has been activated in terminal
Red5 in Ubuntu 12.04 Web browser - Server
Red5 in Windows 7 web browser - Client
Red5 in Oflademo from Ubuntu web browser - NetConnection.Connect.Closed
```

Here are screenshots:

[image: 1]
  [image: 2]
  [image: 3]
  [image: 4]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `oflaDemo` application.

1. In your Ubuntu server, once you are connected to `localhost:5080` , click on **`Install a ready made application`** on the bottom of the page.
2. Select `oflaDemo` on the next page, Install it.
   [image]
3. Then try to establish connection

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mr GoldRolger. For your information, I have installed OflaDemo. But when I connect in OflaDemo, the message says "NetConnection.Connect.Closed". What else do I have to modify ? Or is there anything I miss ? Thank you

Comment: Is der a folder called `oflaDemo` in <red5-dir>/webapps ?

Comment: Yes, there is a folder called oflaDemo in <red5-dir>/webapps. The full path is /opt/red5/webapps/oflaDemo. Is there anything I miss ?

Comment: I have the same problem. oflaDemo installed via :5080/installer/ but demos won't work. (NetConnection.Connect.Failed). Did you find out what was wrong?

Comment: Same problem here as well, and looking for an answer. Of course, none of the above solutions will work (yes, oflaDemo is installed), and no errors whatsoever on any logs.

Answer (score 0):

You should change location to rtmp://your-server-ip/oflaDemo